# How can I get my Script to work on the Login page?

Tags: functions, hooks, login, actions

I am trying to disable the right click feature, on the login page, using the following code:

```
<?php
function disable_right_click() {
?>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(document).bind("contextmenu",function(e){
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
<?php
}
add_action('login_footer', 'disable_right_click', 1);
?>
```

I can see the above code is being parsed in the browser but the right click feature does not seem to be disabled.  The code works, as the right click feature works elsewhere on the website; including in the WP Dashboard.  I have also tried using other hooks, such as `login_form` but to no success.

Is anyone able to advise on how I am able to disable the right click feature, on the login page, with the above code (ideally)?